# Sorting Scores From a File in Python

Tags: python

Here's the part that uses the file:

```
file = open('Dice Game.txt', 'a')
file.write(winner + '\n')
file.close()
file = open('Dice Game.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    name = line.strip()
    print(name)
file.close()
```

I know the part that prints the scores in quite bulky, but that seemed to be the only way I could get it to print correctly.

I've tried loads of different solutions I have found online, but none of them worked to sort the file numerically in descending order (and print the top 5 scores), they all seemed to give errors (when trying to use things such as `sort` and `sorted`).

The variable winner if defined as:

```
winner = str(score) + '=' + str(username)
```

I would like to figure out how I should change that variable or how I can sort it as it is.

Comment: Please show some of your attempts.

Comment: How are you trying to sort? I cannot see your attempt. From the top of my head. This could be close to the solution you need `sorted(map(int,file.readlines()))[:5]`

Comment: If you have tried loads of different solutions you should share some of those as your research, along with your [mcve] and a clear description of any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's store what's in the file.

```
lines = []
for line in file:
    winner = line.strip()  # something like '30=Jim'
    score, name = winner.split('=')  # => '30', 'Jim'

    # now store that information for later
    lines.append((int(score), name))  # we're putting (30, 'Jim') in lines

# lines contains [(30, 'Jim'), (20, 'Amy'), (60, 'Susan'), ...]
print(lines)
```

Can you now use one of the methods you found online to sort `lines`?

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I'd been trying to figure it out for ages. I'm very grateful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

To simply append an entry, you don't need to open the file twice, since you can open in [`r+`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) mode. This will let you read and write. `r` mode puts the file pointer at the beginning of the file rather than at the end. When you open files, you should use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to automatically close the file, even if an error happens:

```
with open('Dice Game.txt', 'r+') as file:
    data = [line.strip() for line in file]
    print(winner, file=file)
data.append(winner)
```

The comprehension that assigns to `data` moves the file pointer to the very end. The `print` statement then writes to the end.

Sorting the data is a whole separate can of worms. You have to split the data and sort by the numerical value of the score. Then you will have to rewrite the whole file. While you can do this with a single open, it would probably be easier to open twice as in your original example:

```
fname = 'Dice Game.txt'
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    data = [int(score), name.rstrip() for score, name in (line.split('=', 1) for line in file)]
data.sort()
with open(fname, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(f'{score}={name}\n' for score, name in data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open("something.txt", r)
contents = file.read()

##Now you may play with the file contents
each_line = contents.split("\n")
##Each line of your file content will be stored in a list
##Access each element as:
for items in each_line:
    print(items)
    ##Do something
##Sorting
contents.sort()
##Now the contents of list are sorted
print(contents)
```

Comment: `Do something` is the question which has not been answered here